# How to pass js variable with ajax to django?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm passing an array in json format with ajax to my django views. I receive status 200 so the POST has been made. The problem is when i try to display the data passed in another template. I receive None in console. Appreciate for any help.
The variable i need to pass to views in array containing jsons. I need to pass it to my views in order to create new object of the model. The below code doesn't work, it returns None.

```
ajax function:
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/order-confirmation',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"array":array},
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded/json",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken":'{{ csrf_token }}'},
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.d);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
  });

urls:
path("order-confirmation", views.order_confirmation, name="confirmation")

views:
@csrf_exempt
def order_confirmation(request):
    array = request.POST.get('array[]')
    context = {
        "array":array
    }
    return render(request, 'main_templates/order_confirmation.html', context)
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="container">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
        <tbody>
          {% for row in seats_range %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="bg-danger">{{row}}</th>
            {% for number in seats_range %}
              <td class="text-center" style="width:5%;" row="{{row}}" onclick="change_bg(this)"><a href="#"></a>{{forloop.counter}}</a></td>
            {% endfor %} 
          </tr>
          {% endfor %} 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'confirmation' %}"><button type="submit" onclick="get_all_fields()">Click me</button></a>
```

Comment: You need to `request.POST.get('array')` since that's what you named it in the json.

Comment: after adding request.method == "POST" I started receiving "The view main.views.order_confirmation didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." :/

Comment: Could you update the code in the question so I can see what/where you're talking about, plz?

Comment: @JDunken did it. All I need is to pass the variable along with redirecting to a new template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you can parse the JSON in view is a little different.
In the function, you can do something like

```
#import json library

def order_confirmation(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    print(data['array'])
    #process the data
    return HttpResponse(status=200) 
  else:
    return render(request, 'main_templates/order_confirmation.html')
```

This makes sure that the variable in ajax is the one being transferred. Check your print also, to confirm that the view is not the issue.
Also in the template, I see you have not mentioned variable called 'array' anywhere, which you used in ajax call. I believe that is for loop variable, correctly replace it

```
{% for row in array %}
```

and then the code should work.
You should then see your template in the console.log

Comment: Good evening, thank you for your answer :) As you can see my button is under <a> tag which redirects to proper url and proper view. Can this be done like that ?

Comment: Hi,The post ajax call will work as it is asynchronous you dont need a redirect ot reload page. Hence when you 'post' the data, your template was loaded into the console as you typed in js. But because you button has a 'href' redirection tag it redirected but now nothing is posted  so  instead None is returned. I am changing the code above, to match what you are requiring in view function.

Comment: Ok, i can see it sending post :) However it send an array of object Object. How can i convert it to readable data ?

Comment: @husa, can you please update the above questions with code, problem and where you are getting it. If you use JSON library. Your output is visible in Django backend.